# Cleaning a USB Drive from sugar grains

Tags: hard-drive, usb, cleaning

I have this dual USB drive from sandisk. When I put it in my backpack there were some spilled sugar grains from packages you get for your tea at hotels which got in the drive. It gnashes every time I try to move the protection. Is there any way in which I could clean it without ruining it?  This here is my usb drive:
https://www.google.ro/search?q=sandisk+dual+usb+drive+16gb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo-dP8kd7SAhUIaRQKHXrqDfgQ_AUICCgB&biw=1518&bih=723#imgrc=DxLzhVkaROfgaM:&spf=207
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a toothbrush to it

Comment: Try blowing it out with canned air.  You may need to open it up.

Comment: Lick it off.  :)

Comment: First try compressed air and see if you can simply force all of the sugar grains out. If that does not work, try a q-tip or cloth and soak it with isopropyl alcohol and try to brush it out (leaving it to completely dry afterwards). DO NOT use water to clean the drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note these two things:

- you may use compressed air to clear some of the sugar grains, but moisture in the air will cause many of them to stick.
  sugar does not conduct electricity, but it is ‘hygroscopic’:  it will attract moisture from the air, and that moisture will permit oxidation and ionization to occur on the circuit boards.
- the use of alcohol in this procedure will at the very least probably smudge the paint or any markings made on the case of the USB stick.

---

1. Obtain the following:

   - isopropyl alcohol (rubbing alcohol, isopropanol) at more than 90% alcohol per volume
   - broad-tip tweezers
   - small bucket
   - ventilated area
2. place materials and the USB stick in the well–ventilated area.
3. holding the USB stick in the tweezers, suspend it halfway down the bucket.
4. begin *slowly* pouring the isopropyl alcohol down over the USB stick, rotating the USB stick as you do so.  be certain to pour the alcohol through every visible crevice.
5. when the USB stick has been thoroughly rinsed, allow it to dry enough for handling.
   attempt to slide the protection sheath.  if it seems rough, then repeat the rinse from step **3**.
6. when the USB stick is completely rinsed, as per your judgment, allow it to dry for ten (10) minutes with good ventilation and in a dry environment (conditions are above dewpoint).  do not apply electrical power, or otherwise attempt to use the USB stick, until it is dry internally!
7. dispose of the waste alcohol in accordance with local environmental maintenance procedures:  it will evaporate rapidly, but the waste will contain various toxic residues.

Disassembly would be the best way to be certain that your USB stick is clean, but if that is not possible or tenable, then you will need to take extra care during your rinse.